# Fetching data from API and displaying results on browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, php-curl

I'm using jQuery to get the values from an HTML input field, pass these values as variables to a PHP file which will accept them as parameters in the URL when connecting to an API.

What I'm trying to achieve is, when a user enters a latitude and longitude value that doesn't match to the data obtained from the API it will ask them to enter another value otherwise it will return the address that matches the values entered.

The data from the API is like:

```
{"address":{"adminCode2":"0363","adminCode1":"07","lng":"4.88132","distance":"0.02","lat":"52.35792"}}
```

HTML code is:

```
Latitude: <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" placeholder="52.358">
Longitude: <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" placeholder="4.881">
```

jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "libs/php/getAddress.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        latitude: $("#latitude").val(),
        longitude: $("#longitude").val(),
      },
      success: function (result, status, xhr) {
        console.log(result);
        if ($("#latitude").val() == result.address.lat && $("#longitude").val() == result.address.lng){
          $("#result").html(
            "Address: " +
              result.address.houseNumber +
              " " +
              result.address.street +
              "<br>" +
              result.address.locality +
              "<br>" +
              result.address.postalcode
          );
        } else {
        $("#result").html("There are no nearest street or address with the given latitude & longitude.  Please enter another value");
        }
      },
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
$longitude=$_POST['longitude'];

$url = "http://api.geonames.org/addressJSON?lat=".$latitude."&lng=".$longitude."&username=username";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
     echo $e;
}
else {
$decoded = json_decode($response, true);
// print "<PRE>";
// print_r($decoded);
$encoded = json_encode($decoded);
echo ($encoded);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

When I run the above code I get these errors in the console if the value entered isn't in the data, but if I enter the right value it will display the address:

```
{status: {…}}
status: {message: "missing parameter lat", value: 14}
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

Comment: I think you are missing the property of data.
result.data.address, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the data returned is valid by checking if the members exist.

```
// Check if the members exist for whichever members you want to access

if(result != null && result.address != null && result.address.lat != null)
{

}
```